# Android how to deny the permission which is already

Tags: java, android

Here is my java code

```
 cameraSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked){
                        strName="Camera";
                        checkAndRequestPermissions();
                    }                  }
                }
            });
 public  void checkAndRequestPermissions(){
            int camera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
            List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(strName.equals("Camera")){
                if (camera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                }
            }
            if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            }
    }

      @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                    if(strName.equals("Camera")){
                        if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            cameraSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                            cameraSwitch.setChecked(true);
                        }else if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                            cameraSwitch.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am implementing run time permissions in my android application.i have switch button if i click  the switch button i am granting camera permission similarly i want to deny the permission when switch button becomes deactive.please help me to deny the permission when switch button is deactivated.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to deny the permission when switch button becomes
> deactive.please help me to deny the permission when switch button is
> deactivated.

there is no way to remove the gran programmatically. What you can do is to forward the user to your app's setting screen. There the user can revoke the permission

Answer (score 0):

Try this code that opens the settings screen of the app, so the user will be able to deny the permissions from there:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
i.setData(uri);
startActivity(i);
```